# Why flask won't found module flask_mysqldb?

Tags: python

I'm losing my mind!
I've tried all the things I've found on the internet,
but it won't work!

with
dirProject
|app.py
|flask
|    |bin
|    |    |activate

when I do pip instal flask_mysqldb from dirProject, I get "requirement already satisfied,
but when I do

```
$ source flask/bin/activate
$ flask run
```

I get module not found

Can anyone help me ? :(

ps: I'm on a raspberry using raspbian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

delete virtualenv and recreate it then install the requirements and it will work

create new :

```
virtualenv flask

source bin/activate
```

after you create this install the requirements

```
pip install flask
```